# I just want to see the email address in the Apple ID

Tags: ipad, apple-id

A teacher found a school iPad 2, used by a former student, as a loaner, in the back of the iPad cart and they put their info into the apple id. So, we're locked out.

I just want to SEE the email from the Apple ID, so I can send a request, to the student, to remove the device from their iTunes account. How do I go about seeing the email, instead of d****@yahoo.com?  Did factory restore but, nothing opened up. Can't follow Apple's instructions for recovering because I have No ID or email address and they want one or the other.

Comment: Have you looked at [Apple Configurator](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12) to prevent students doing that in future?

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to find that info.  If you don't have the email address and the password you can't see that type of info.

I don't think Apple can see that info, either.  You'll have to take it to them, with proof of ownership, and they can reset the device.  You can contact them at getsupport.apple.com for additional help.

Comment: If the device is owned by the school, and the school or Apple has a record of ownership, they will remove the Apple ID hold on the device. We do this several times a year.  Since we purchase in bulk from Apple, and use DEP for app deployment, Apple already has a list of the serial numbers for all our devices and it makes it easy.